# How to pass a doGet(e) parameter to another function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am able to capture a variable from the url of a published app script, but I am not sure how I can pass that variable to another function.   The below script will not run the onRun function if a variable is included.  My goal is to pass 2 variables, but one problem at a time.

```
function doGet(e) {

    var id = e.parameter.id;
    var minutes = e.parameter.min;


  var html = '<p>'
  +'<button onClick=google.script.run.onRun('+id+')>Run</button>' // Does not work when clicked
    +'<button onClick=google.script.run.onRun()>Run without parameter</button>'
  +'<button onClick=google.script.run.turnOn()>On</button>'
  +'<button onClick=google.script.run.turnOff()>Off</button>'
  +'</p>';

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

}

function onRun(id){
  Logger.log("id: "+id); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to use a public cache (Thank you Sandy Good).

```
function doGet(e) {

    var id = e.parameter.id;
    var minutes = e.parameter.min;

  var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();
  cache.put("id", id, 30);
  cache.put("minutes", minutes, 30);

  var html = '<p>'
    +'<button onClick=google.script.run.onRun()>Run without parameter</button>'
  +'<button onClick=google.script.run.turnOn()>On</button>'
  +'<button onClick=google.script.run.turnOff()>Off</button>'
  +'</p>';

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

}

function onRun(id){
  var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();
var id = cache.get('id'));
var minutes = cache.get('minutes'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Either use a global variable, or put the values into cache.

To declare a global variable, declare the variable outside of a function:

```
var id = "";
var minutes = "";

function doGet(e) {

  id = e.parameter.id;
  minutes = e.parameter.min;

  var html = . . . . . HTML HERE;

  onRun(id, minutes);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

}
```

Or put the values into Cache:

```
function doGet(e) {

  var id = e.parameter.id;
  var minutes = e.parameter.min;

  if (!!id) {cache.put('theid', id, 4000);};
  if (!!minutes) {cache.put('min', minutes, 4000);};

  var html = . . . . . HTML HERE;

  onRun(id, minutes);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

}
```

Then you can retrieve the values from cache, or use the global variable anywhere in your code.

So, you don't need to pass anything from the HTML to the `.gs` code.

I don't see anything calling the `onRun()` function within the `doGet()` function.

You *can* call another function from the `doGet()` function, as long as it's *before* the `return`.  `return` stops the function at that point.

```
function doGet(e) {

  var id = e.parameter.id;
  var minutes = e.parameter.min;

  var html = . . . . . HTML HERE;

  onRun(id, minutes);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

}
```

You can't have:

```
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  onRun(id, minutes);
```

You can also trigger script to run from an HTML Script tag with `window.onload = function() {code};`:

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    console.log("This onload did run");
    code here;
  };
</script>
```

To pass multiple variables, just separate them by a comma:

```
function doGet(e) {

  code here;

  onRun(id, minutes);
}

function onRun(argId, argMinutes) {
  Logger.log('argId: ' + argId);
  Logger.log('argMinutes: ' + argMinutes);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description, and I understand what you are saying.   However I want the variables to pass to the onRun() function  when a button in clicked.   This means that the onRun(id,min) (or google.script.run.onRun(id,min)) needs to be ran from the HtmlService instead of the directly from gs file.

Comment: You don't need to pass the variables.  You need to put the values into Cache or into a global variable.  See my updated answer.

Comment: I had tested using a private cache and it produced an error, when I switched to a public one, everything stated working as it should.  I posted a second answer with updated code from my original post.