# Message after form submit in iFrame with Google Script doPost

Tags: google-apps-script, forms

I have a simple form inside an iFrame submitting to GAS Web App:

```
<form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AK...a4/exec" method="POST">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="email" name="email" value="">
    <br><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="Inv">
    <input type="submit" value="DOWNLOAD" style="margin:0px auto; display:block; width: 10em;  height: 2.4em;">
</form>
```

I want to send back to the iFrame a message from the doPost service, for example:

```
function doPost(e) {
...
var response = "<HTML><BODY><H1>Error processing request</H1><BR><BR><P>Missing or invalid parameter in request.</P></BODY></HTML>"
   return ContentService.createTextOutput(response).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT); 
}
```

However, the iFrame is cleared empty after the submit, and never displays my message. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service), use `createTextOutput(content)` method to create a new [`TextOutput`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/text-output) object that can serve the given content. Try using this sample code:

```
function doGet() {
    var output = ContentService.createTextOutput("Hello world!");
    return output;
}
```

To further use your code, try also removing HTML tags within your `doPost()` function and see if it works.

Lastly, please also check solution given in this SO post - [HTML Form does not submit to spreadsheet using doPost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098109/html-form-does-not-submit-to-spreadsheet-using-dopost). It might also help.

Comment: Thanks! I implemented an XMLHttpRequest against a doGet in GAS, as per the example link you provided - the client iFrame receives no response. Apparently it is a known unsupported feature by Google: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1563 it seems I have no way to implement a two-way HTTP communication here...

Comment: I also tried implementing with JSONP but the response does not pass through to the browser, probably because of google redirect. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#serving_jsonp_in_web_pages